# signalR first demo project

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am new to SignalR and I am looking for a sample application in Asp.net not mvc that does real time notifications so that I can start working. Can any one guide me to a working sample because I have downloaded many samples that do not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please note that this answer was for SignalR version 0.5.3 and is now out of date with the latest version of SignalR**

It is really simple just to set up your own little Demo. There really isn't much to it.
Just create a new project, install SignalR via the NuGet package manager console, and then do the very basics to get it running.

I blogged about how to do it over at my site http://timjames.me/creating-your-first-signalr-mvc-project

**Hub**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SignalR;
using SignalR.Hubs;

namespace MySignalR
{
    public class SNRL : Hub
    {
        public void SendMessage(string msg)
        {
            Clients.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

**Javscript**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var myHub = $.connection.sNRL;
        myHub.sendMessage = function (data) {
            $('#mySpanTag').html(data);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto' }, function () {
            myHub.sendMessage("Hello World!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**html**

```
<span id="mySpanTag"></span>
```

And make sure you reference the correct script files

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried downloading the SignalR sample from NuGet Library?